# TypeORM : Generate query with nested AND and OR

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am using NodeJS + TypeORM + PostgreSQL

I find it difficult to generate queries based on my requirements.

I need to generate the following query:

```js
select * from clinics where status = 1 and (last_sync_date < x or last_sync_date is null)
```

Here **x** is current date - 10 days.

I tried the following query:

```js
let now = Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 10);

let clinics = await clinicRepo.find({
  where: [
    { status: 1, last_sync_date: LessThan(now) },
    { last_sync_date: IsNull() }
  ]
});
```

But the result is this:

```js
select * from clinics where (status = 1 and last_sync_date < x) or last_sync_date is null;
```

What do I need to change in the code above?

I want to use **find** so that I can load relations as well.

Comment: You can just add `status: 1` to the second where query and it should work

Comment: Actually I'm generating the above where dynamically which could have any number of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating the query with js conditions and then assign it to the FindConditions.

For example:

```
 const whereCondition = testResultId ?
            {patientId, id: Not(testResultId), clinicId} :
            {patientId, clinicId}

 const tr = await TestResult.findOne({
            where: whereCondition,
        })
```

Or you can use Raw operator:

```
 let clinics= await clinicRepo.find({
    where : [
        {status: 1,
         last_sync_date: Raw(alias => `(${alias} < ${now} OR ${alias} IS NULL)`}
    ]
 });
```